# How to get data from a database using a loop?

Tags: arrays, json, ajax, loops

In my database I've got different username: "fabio97", "antonino", "lauretta". I want to get them from DB to have an array like this:

```
$dati = array("str"=>array("n1"=>"fabio97", "n2"=>"antonino", "n3"=>"lauretta"));
```

is it correct write:

```
...
    "str" => array("n".$i=>"Ti sei incrociato con ".$array_db[username]),
...
```

into a loop

```
...
$i = 0;
$array_user = mysql_fetch_array($query);
while ($array_db = mysql_fetch_array ($query_db)) {
    ...
        if ($array_user[square] == $array_db[square]) {
            $dati = array(
                "data" => array(
                    'address_complete'=>$data->results[0]->formatted_address, 
                    'address_square'=>$data->results[0]->address_components[1]->long_name,
                    'location'=>$data->results[0]->address_components[2]->long_name,
                    'postal_code'=>$data->results[0]->address_components[7]->long_name,
                    'data_ora'=>$tmp_date
                ),
                "str" => array("n".$i=>"Ti sei incrociato con ".$array_db[username]),
                "index" => $i
            );
            $i++;
        }
}
```

and to call them with Ajax:

```
... success:function(msg){
    if(msg){
       $("#location").html(Object.keys(msg.str).map(x => msg.str[x]).join(", "));
    }else{
        $("#location").html('Not Available');
    }
```

Comment: try it and you'll see if it's correct.

Comment: I've ask because it isn't correct. In fact it says only the latest data saved in database. @JulienBernu

Comment: @Fabio97 then tell us the problem - just posting your code and saying theres an error isn't enough. If you want help, give us the possibility to help. Provide a [mcve]